# Finding solutions to the equation a + b + gcd(a, b) = n

Tags: math, equation

I have a question that, we are given n; We should find different two numbers: `a` and `b`, such that, `a + b + gcd(a, b) = n`. How can we find it?

Comment: This is probably a question for [math.se] since it doesn't ask anything about programming

Answer (score 2):

```
 a + b + gcd(a, b) = 
 gcd(a, b) * da + gcd(a, b) * db + gcd(a, b) =
 gcd(a, b)* (da + db + 1)
```

So you have to get arbitrary factorization of  `n` into two divisors, assign one `divisor >= 3` to the sum `d = (da + db + 1)`, and another divisor to `gcd(a, b)`.

Subdivide `d-1` value into two mutual prime parts `da` and `db`

Example (just some possible solutions for "universal answer value"):

```
n = 42 = 6 x 7
da + db + 1 = 6
da = 2  //arbitrary subdivision, da is mutual prime with db, OK
db = 3
gcd = 7
a = 14
b = 21
n = 14 + 21 + 7 = 42

da = 1  //arbitrary subdivision
db = 4
a = 7
b = 28
n = 7 + 28 + 7 = 42

da + db + 1 = 7
da = 2 // Error - gcd(da,db)>1, they are not mutual prime, subdivision is not suitable
db = 4

da = 1  //it's OK
db = 5

gcd = 6
6 + 30 + 6 = 42

n = 14 * 3
da = 5, db = 8
15 + 24 + 3 = 42
```

Comment: @Shahin Alekberli Is my answer unclear?

Comment: @Shahin Alekberli - please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" this answer.